loading data (faled)from json file in angular 18 app using json server
this is my  db.json file
{
  "locations": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Acme Fresh Start Housing",
      "city": "Chicago",
      "state": "IL",
      "photo": "https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1436217023/photo/exterior-of-a-blue-suburban-home.jpg?s=1024x1024&w=is&k=20&c=AZKMyi9tKbOYS5lNCNvRxOfahxo__p_s-Lb8JTXVvqY=",
      "availableUnits": 4,
      "wifi": true,
      "laundry": true
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "A113 Transitional Housing",
      "city": "Santa Monica",
      "state": "CA",
      "photo": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1588880331179-bc9b93a8cb5e?w=500&auto=format&fit=crop&q=60&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTJ8fGhvdXNlJTIwanBnfGVufDB8fDB8fHww",
      "availableUnits": 0,
      "wifi": false,
      "laundry": true
    },]}

I execute this   json-server --watch db.json command in my vscode
terminal and this is  the output :
--watch/-w can be omitted, JSON Server 1+ watches for file changes by default
JSON Server started on PORT :3000
Press CTRL-C to stop
Watching db.json...

(˶ᵔ ᵕ ᵔ˶)
Index:
http://localhost:3000/
Static files:
Serving ./public directory if it exists
Endpoints:
No endpoints found, try adding some data to db.json
this is how the url look like :[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/lQKFuED9.png)

Are you execute the json-server in the same folder you have your file db.json? BTW, I think that you need use: localhost:3000/locations to get the array locations and, e.g. localhost:3000/locations/1 to get the second location. See the docs
